# java jama array problem

Tags: java, math, svd, jama

I asked a question before but duffymo said it is not clear so i am going to post it again here. 
I am using Jama api for SVD calculation. I know very well about jama and SVD. 
Jama does not work if your column are more than rows. I have this situation. What should I do?? any help?
I can't transpose the matrix too as it can produce wrong results. 
Thanks.

P.S: I am calculating LSI with the help of jama. I am going like column(docs) and rows ( terms )

Comment: Usually if your question is unclear, you can edit the original question besides posting a new one

Comment: And even if you have a valid reason to post a new version of another question, it's nice to link to the original so we can read the comments there and see what the difference is this time.

Comment: thanks, I will keep this in my mind. 
so any help? advice ?

Answer (score 1):

If I understand correctly you are trying to compute the SVD of a matrix which is not square, and you have the library JAMA which only works on square matrices?  If I have understood you correctly then the answer to your question is obvious: Get a library which does compute SVD for non-square matrices. If I remember correctly Numerical Recipes contains such an algorithm, I expect you can find many other sources with Google.

Comment: Hi, Thanks for your reply. Yes you understand my problem 100% correctly. I couldn't find any good java API for SVD. can you please tell me one??? also jama is veyr slow it took 2 hours to calculate SVD on 500 column matrix

Answer (score 1):

Why not use transpose? If X = USV', then X' = VS'U'. Right?

Transpose your matrix. Get U, S and V. Transpose everything back.

Comment: for LSI it should be term by document so you can not transpose

Answer (score 0):

Since you're doing LSI, you could use SVDLIBJ, which is the Java equivalent of SVDLIBC, which is one of the most scalable SVD implementations that is freely available.  The S-Space package has a [command-line tool for SVDLIBJ](http://code.google.com/p/airhead-research/downloads/detail?name=svd.jar&can=2&q=) set up already.  Also, you can use their Matrix libraries and avoid the command-line if that fits your needs better.

Answer (score 0):

I now it is a really late reply . But i thought it is better late than never

But i am aware that [jblas](http://jblas.org/) performs svd in a effective manner.